# Tomcat 7 & 8 do not start under YOSEMITE and Java JDK SE 8 - missing ExtendedPlatformComponent

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, java-8

Maybe someone did have this before (and possibly solved it)

On a mac book pro with Yosemite I installed Java 8 "1.8.0_40-ea" with JDK.

My `$JAVA_HOME` is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home`

Then I downloaded a tomcat 8 core from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi
When I start this tomcat 8 I get the following Java exception - see below.

With this Java 8 also my older tomcat 7 throws the same exception.

It seems that `sun/management/ExtendedPlatformComponent` be not part of tomcat 8 nor java 8

The method `ExtendedPlatformComponent` should be inside a `rt.jar` file but is not. This seems to be a bug in JDK SE 8 for mac :(

Does anyone have some hints for me? I cannot figure our what is wrong ... I would simply add that class to `rt.jar` but cannot even find that class...

```
PS: The exception on start (/bin/startup.sh):
22-Nov-2014 18:43:02.218 SEVERE [main]
    org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement Begin event threw
    error * java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/management/ExtendedPlatformComponent*
        at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(ManagementFactory.java:494)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.getMBeanServer(Registry.java:443)
        at ...
```

Comment: I think you might be right given `java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer` is the second line in your stacktrace, but you might be able to work around it. Have you looked at the `Registry.java` source from your version of Tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with update 40 Early Access release of jre/jdk8(1.8.0_40). Compared with update 20 of jre/jdk8 release, you will see following lines of code has been added to getPlatfromMBeanServer:

```
        for (final PlatformManagedObject o :
                                   ExtendedPlatformComponent.getMXBeans()) {
            if (!platformMBeanServer.isRegistered(o.getObjectName())) {
                addMXBean(platformMBeanServer, o);
            }
```

But if you look into the accompanied rt.jar of the jre, this newly introduced class(ExtendedPlatformComponent) can NO-WHERE be found.

This issue, seems to be there across all the JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_40" EA release, irrespective of platform.

Your remedy is to move back to a stable release. Latest stable release seems to be Java SE 8u25.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, upgraded to 1.8.0_40 ea build 20 (released on 31 December 2014) and that fixed it.